# Universal reference, infer std::list<T> and T

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

This is a long shot, however I'm trying to infer a universal reference of type `std::list<T>` for some `T`.

I have something like this:

```
// Is the type A the same as B, regardless of const and references
template <typename A, typename B>
struct is_same_kind {
    static constexpr auto value = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<A>>,
                                                 std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<B>>>;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
static constexpr auto is_same_kind_v = is_same_kind<A,B>::value;

template<typename L, typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_same_kind_v<L, std::list<T>>>>
T head(L&& l) {
   return *std::forward<L>(l).begin();
}
```

I get an error as the preprocessor is not able to infer `T`. Maybe there's some nice trick to infer both `L&&` as universal reference to `std::list<T>` and the type `T` from the argument `l`?

EDIT: Here's how to call it for example:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << head(std::list{1,2,3});
}
```

I expect to get 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I found a way to do this by defaulting to the `value_type` member. I'm calling `remove_reference_t<L>` first, as `L& :: value_type` won't work if it's passed by lvalue reference.

```
template<typename L, typename T = typename std::remove_reference_t<L>::value_type, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_same_kind_v<L, std::list<T>>>>
T head(L&& l) {
   return *std::forward<L>(l).begin();
}

int main() {
   std::cout << head(std::list{1,2,3});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your original question, but an important point on the implementation of your function. The way you use the captured value is incorrect. For `int`s it doesn't matter, because there is nothing to move, but for some types it does matter (especially for those for which `L&&` makes real sense). For example:

```
template<typename L>
auto head(L&& l) {
    return *std::forward<L>(l).begin();
}

int main() {
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> list;
    list.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(1));
    list.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(2));

    auto z = head(std::move(list));
    return 0;
}
```

This code will not even compile. Here one is trying to make a copy of `std::unique_ptr` because `*it` is not moved from.

First, there is no much sense in calling `begin()` on a forwarded value. The only choice a compiler has is to call either `begin()` or `begin() const` and this choice does not depend on the value category of `l`. The resulting iterator is not automatically an `std::move_iterator` if `begin()` is called on an rvalue. Second, you should `std::move` from `*it` if an rvalue is passed into the function. So, the `head(...)` function might look like this (using some nice C++17 features):

```
template<typename L>
auto head(L&& l) {
    if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<L&&>)
        return std::move(*l.begin());
    else
        return *l.begin();
}
```

Instead of `*l.begin()` we could use `l.front()`. The same arguments still apply.

Comment: What’s the difference between your ‘constexpr’ and ‘std::forward’? AFAIK ‘std::forward’ applied to an rvalue reference has the same effect as ‘std::move’.

Comment: @rausted, the difference is very important: you're applying `std::forward` to `l` itself (and it is a no-op in that case), but not to `*l.begin()`, as you should. `std::move(*l.begin())` and `*std::move(l).begin()` are very different things. Just try to compile my first example and you'll see.

Comment: @rausted, you can't use `std::forward` without specifying a template type parameter explicitly. If you specify the correct `T` in `std::forward<T>`, it would work. But constructing this `T` will boil down to similar checking whether `L&&` is an rvalue reference (or whether `L` is an lvalue reference) and using `std::conditional_t`. Something like `using T = decltype(*l.begin()); using FT = std::conditional_t<std::is_rvalue_reference_v<L&&>, std::remove_reference_t<T>, T>; return std::forward<FT>(*l.begin());` (untested). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411192/1625187